# Communicate between a web site and InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a mobile App launching InAppBrowser:

```
const browser = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes,usewkwebview=yes');

    browser.addEventListener('loadstart', async (e) => {
      ...
    });
```

When navigating on my site, if I click on a specific `button`, I'd like to send a message to my mobile app so it can do an action. Is there anyway I could do that ? 
One hacky way is to change the `window.location.href` so it does trigger a `loadstart` with some queryParams, but it forces to reload my page at the very least.

EDIT:

This seems to be a lead

```
if (window['webkit'] && window['webkit'].messageHandlers && window['webkit'].messageHandlers['cordova_iab']
            && window['webkit'].messageHandlers['cordova_iab'].postMessage) {
                window['webkit'].messageHandlers['cordova_iab'].postMessage(JSON.stringify({'data': 'value'}))
}
```